# Pulling data from MongoDB existing databas with Django(Djongo)

Tags: django, mongodb

So i am working on a proyect with mongodb and django(djongo) and i have to use an already existing database(MongoDB compass) and i cant find the way to pull or import the information from MongoDB, already try with: python manage.py inspectdb > models.py and python manage.py inspectdb and when create the models.py is not with the database instead it pulls the default MongoDb, already try the Documentation of django and nothing works. Anyone got some info about it?

PD: my app is totally empty and already configured the settings.py as the documentation on Django instruct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

in your model you should specify db_table same as the collection name in your Mongo database

Comment: To be more specific, try to elaborate on why your solution would solve the OPs problem.

Comment: if the collection in your database is called "events" for exemple then add in your models.py in class Meta db_table = "events".                                                        class Event(models.Model):                                                                                                          topic = models.CharField(max_length=70)                                                                     class Meta:
        db_table = 'events'